# Avoiding do statement in foldM

Tags: haskell

```
g ll = 
  foldlM (\ some_list b -> do
    part <- f b
    return (some_list ++ part)) [] ll
```

In above piece of code I use `do statement` just because the `f` function return a monad type:  `M a` where `a` is a list.
( I "unpack" that list with `<-`. This is why I need `do statement`). Can I avoid it and write that more concisely? ( Yes, I know that I can write it using `>>=` but I also consider something nicer.)

Comment: You want `fmap :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`.

Comment: g looks at first glance as `fmap concat (mapM f ll)`

Comment: Like that: `g = foldlM (\some_list b -> (some_list++) <$> f b) []`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`foldlM` is the wrong tool for the job. You can use it, as chepner's answer shows, but the way you're concatenating lists could get expensive. Luka Rahne's one-liner is much better:

```
g ll = fmap concat (mapM f ll)
```

Another option is to use `foldr` directly:

```
g = foldr (\x r -> (++) <$> f x <*> r) (pure [])
```

Another way to write the second version, by inlining the `foldr`:

```
g [] = pure []
g (x : xs) = (++) <$> f x <*> g xs
```

Comment: What's the difference (after you turn `some_list ++ part` into `part ++ some_list`)? It looks to me like all three versions are equivalent and they all leak. `g` [can](http://lpaste.net/350227) be defined more efficiently for monoids other than `[]` (`Sum` e.g.), but I don't think there is a version that produces lists lazily and thus doesn't leak. So it's just lists are a wrong tool, when big lists are involved.

Comment: @user3237465, you can get away with it if you're dealing with a lazy `Applicative`. Otherwise, yes, they all leak space. I was addressing the fact that the badly-associated `++`s also lead to a time-complexity problem regardless of the context.

Comment: @dfeuer thanks! :)
The first version is understandable, but the second I cannot  grasp

Answer (score 1):

Your `do` expression

```
do
  part <- f b
  return (some_list ++ part)
```

follows the extract-apply-return pattern that `fmap` captures (due to the identity `fmap f k = k >>= return . f`

1. You extract `part` from the computation `f b`
2. You apply `(some_list ++)` to `part`
3. You return the result of that application.

This can be done in one step with `fmap`:

```
-- foldlM (f b >>= return . (some_list ++)) [] ll
foldlM (\some_list b -> fmap (some_list ++) (f b)) [] ll
```

Comment: `some_list` is part of the fold. I think Luka Rahne hit the nail on the head.

Comment: Right, I got rid of the entire function instead of just the `do` expression. That's fixed.

Comment: The quadratic complexity remains unfortunate.